# Move file only if another file with different suffix exists

Tags: bash, find, mv

Script hit walltime before completing; creates files from an initial set of input files into output files with different suffix, eg.

file1.ext -> file1.oxt

(note, extensions given are arbitrary).

How do I move only the input files for which there already exist output files into a separate directory before re-running the initial script? Something like 'mv file only if basename(file).oxt exists'. Could do this is other languages, but my knowledge of Bash is extremely lacking here.

Thanks!

Comment: Additional details would be helpful. What parameters would you pass to the script? Source directory and target directory? And how does the script know the target extension for a given source extension? That is, if I see `foo.ext` how would I know to look for `*.oxt` rather than `*.axt` (or whatever)? Are these mappings stored somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

There is your bash script:

```
for file in `ls *.old`
do
    BASE="${file%.*}"
    if [[ -e ${BASE}.new ]]
    then
        mv $file /yourdir/
    fi
done
```

Just replace .old and .new with your suffixes and yourdir with your real directory.

Comment: `ls` output is for human consumption - you're not supposed to use it as input data: your code will fail if any of the filenames contains IFS characters; loop over the glob results - that should be bullet-proof as long as you _quote your vars_

Answer (score 0):

**find** + **bash** solution:

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.oxt" -exec bash -c 'f=$1; 
        fp="${f%.*}"; [[ -f "$fp.oxt" ]] && mv "$f" dest_dir/' _ {} \;
```

---

- `f=$1` - the full filepath
- `fp="${f%.*}"` - filepath with extension stripped(without extension)
- `[[ -f "$fp.oxt" ]]` - check if the respective "output" file exists
- `mv "$f" dest_dir/` - move the initial file to `dest_dir` directory